# PHP MySQL table mouse-over event to display information stored in MySQL (using Dreamweaver)

Tags: php, mysql, mouseevent, dreamweaver

I have a database of players and their info in mysql. I have created a table in dreamweaver displaying all the players and their info. I want to display a player profile (which is stored in mysql) seperate from this table and want this information to change when the mouse is over a player in the table.
Is this possible and how do i go about it? Any help or links to tutorials will be greatly received!
I have a Screenshot of my page but am unable to post due to reputation if anyone wants to visualise my idea maybe i could send it them?

```
<div class="playerInfoContainer">
        <table width="95%" border="0" cellpadding="3">
          <caption>
            Player Profile
          </caption>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['PlayerProfile']; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>  

<div class="squadListContainer">
    <div class="DatabaseContainer">
        <table width="95%" border="0" cellpadding="3">
          <caption>
            Bedlinog Veterans Squad
          </caption>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Player Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Position</th>
            <th scope="col">Date of Birth</th>
            <th scope="col">Points Tally</th>
            <th scope="col">Man of the Matches</th>
          </tr>
          <?php do { ?>
            <tr>
              <td width="130"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['PlayerName']; ?></td>
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Position']; ?></td>
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['DateOfBirth']; ?></td>
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['PointsTally']; ?></td>
              <td width="100"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['MOM']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Basically i want to select a player in the table by running the mouse over him to display his profile in a seperate table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, pre-build all of the displayed mouse-over data into separate XML/JSON files. That way there's no load on a database to display 15 items at once when someone goes nuts with their cursor.

Secondly, use jquery to display a mouseover event to populate a div on the page with the separate HTML files.

As long as your jquery is correct and your css skills are up to snuff, the details will change as required and maintain the correct look/feel as it goes from one 'team/squad' to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Do you know for any good tutorials for any of the above?

Comment: Can i get some examples of the above. I understand what you want me to do but dont have the skills to put it into code.